# TFS 2010 clear SystemAssignedTo in transition

Tags: tfs, workitem

We have introduced a "Code review" state for tasks, between "In progress" and "Done". When moving from "In progress" to "Code review" we would like to clear/unassign System.AssignedTo but I can't figure out how. Does anyone know where to put the logic in the WIT xml and what it should look like?

Thanks,
Mansos

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open your schema in an XML editor. Go down to the `<TRANSITIONS>` part and add

```
<TRANSITION from="In Progress" to="Code Review">
   <FIELDS>
      <FIELD name="Assigned To">
         <EMPTY />
      </FIELD>
   <FIELDS>
</TRANSITION>
```

Make sure you don't have any `<REQUIRED>` for that field anywhere in the definition (there are a number of ways you can have that rule).

For reference, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337653%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: Required was the problem. Thanks!